# Empty var in second service function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a service:

```
.service('VacanciesService', function($http) {
var vacancies = [];
var usedVacancies = [];
return {
    getVacanciesForUniversity: function(university_id) {
        return $http.get("http://jobs.app/api/vacancies/" + university_id).then(function(response){
            vacancies = response.data.vcancies;
            return vacancies;
        }, function(error){
            return error;
        });
    },
    getRandomVacancy: function() {
        console.log(vacancies);
    }
}
```

})

This is the calling controller

```
.controller('jobsCtrl', function($ionicLoading, locker, UniversitiesService, VacanciesService) {
var vm = this;

user = locker.get('userDetails');
UniversitiesService.getUniversity(user.university.id).then(function(university) {
    vm.university = university.university;
});
    VacanciesService.getVacanciesForUniversity(user.university.id).then(function(vacancies) {
    vm.vacancies = vacancies;
}, function error(error) {

});

vm.addCard = function(name) {
    newVacancy = VacanciesService.getRandomVacancy();
};

vm.addCard();
```

})

And I can't figure out why the vacancies variable in in the console.log is empty in the second function? I assumed as it was set in the initial function (called prior) that it should be populated?

TIA!

Comment: Who called the `VacanciesService.getVacanciesForUniversity` function?

Comment: Here is a very basic fiddle, compare yours to this, add more logging perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/f6fem2h2/

Answer (score 0):

if you call `getVacanciesForUniversity` `getRandomVacancy` like below, you will get empty array

```
VacanciesService.getVacanciesForUniversity(uniId)

VacanciesService.getRandomVacancy() //you will get empty
```

you must `getRandomVacancy` inside getVacanciesForUniversity returned promise

```
 VacanciesService.getVacanciesForUniversity(uniId).then(function(){
       VacanciesService.getRandomVacancy()
 })
```

alo you misstype `response.data.vcancies;` instead `response.data.vacancies;`

Comment: in your example there isnt axaj request

Answer (score 0):

The answer is READ YOUR CODE PROPERLY.

There was a glaringly obvious typo in my code that I missed from staring at it too long.

Big thanks to Daniel Dawes and aseferov for attempting to help!

Comment: Yes I see... vacancies = response.data.vcancies;

Answer (score 0):

In your service :

```
getVacanciesForUniversity: function(university_id) {
    return $http.get("http://jobs.app/api/vacancies/" + university_id);
}
```

In your controller :

```
 $scope.getVacancies = function () {
your_service.getVacanciesForUniversity().then(
    function(response) {
        if (response.status = 200) {
              $scope.vacancies = response.data.vacancies;
        }, function errorCallback (response) {
            ...
        }
);
};


$scope.getVacancies(); // you call one time your function here

$scope.getRandomVacancy : function() {
     console.log($scope.vacancies); 
};
```